# На странице профиля пользователя противоречие статуса зарегистрирован и не зарегистрирован

Tags: дефект

В одной части страницы профиля пишется - что пользователь зарегистрирован, а в другой стороне - пишется, что не зарегистрирован.

[Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/238349/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82) на профиль, где был обнаружен данный дефект.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но противоречие действительно есть, можно как-нибудь поменять строки.

Comment: @NickVolynkin получается, членство (member) не подразумевает обязательность регистрации. Можно перевести "member since today" как "участник менее суток", например.

Comment: @NickVolynkin думаю было бы лучше конкретно написать, что пользователь допустим авторизирован через какого-то провайдера, но на сайте не имеет зарегистрированного аккаунта. Ну, как-то это сформулировать только правильно.

Comment: @ragmon «не зарегистрирован» — это даже не авторизован через провайдера. Просто зашёл, задал вопрос, оставил только свою почту (возможно, ненастоящую, она вроде даже не проверяется). Надо подумать над хорошей формулировкой.